# Domain user cannot access to his shared folder after deleting that user

Tags: active-directory, network-share

I've created an shared folder in domain and user was able to access that shared folder with his permission but after deleting that user he cannot access to that shared folder. I've created that user with same name again but problem is not solved. Please help me, Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you see if you look at the folder permissions as they are now, when the user can't access the folder?

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior. Each user account is unique. You created a new user account with the same username but this is not the same user account as the deleted user account. You'll need to grant the new user account permissions to the folder.

Comment: You mean that every user account has unique SID and currently created user account cannot access to this shared folder? right?

Comment: Yes. The new user account is not the same as the old user account.

Comment: Thanks joeqwerty, But now how can I recover the files that into the shared folder?

Comment: What do you mean "recover?"  The files are still there, so once you give the new account permission that allow it to access the files, you're done.